# How do I receive data in a C++ client's main loop without closing the server socket?

Tags: c++, sockets

I was reading [this winsock example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737591%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I am trying to conceptualize how you would create a C++ client program that has a persistent TCP/IP connection to a C# .NET server.

The problem I see is that in order for the C++ client to leave the receive loop, the server must close its socket connection to the client.

In my case the server will send to the client every couple seconds. I need to be able to receive one packet from the server and restart the main program loop so the client can perform the rest of its functionality.

If this receive code is in the C++ client's main loop, the client will never stop receiving if the server never closes the connection to the client:

```
// Receive until the peer closes the connection

do {

    iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
    if ( iResult > 0 )
        printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
    else if ( iResult == 0 )
        printf("Connection closed\n");
    else
        printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

} while( iResult > 0 );
```

Comment: Put your other work *inside* the loop.

Comment: SO is a question-and-answer site, not a blog. If you have a question, please include it in your post.

Comment: use non-blocking sockets and select.

Comment: @Rob Question: How do you receive 1 packet in the C++ client and then go back to the main loop; without the server closing its socket connection? I have the C# server working, and I have the C++ example running, however I can't figure out how to only receive 1 packet at a time on the C++ client. The server will just keep sending packet after packet and the client is stuck in the loop, even though the packets are multiple seconds apart.

Comment: How does your protocol identify the distinct packets? Are they all fixed size? Do they all end in `'\n'`? Do they have a length field?

Comment: @Rob The packets are ASCII encoded, they all start with $ and end with #. The packets are not a fixed size.

Comment: What do you do with this '$#' protocol-unit when you have it - does the 'main loop' need this data, or can you handle it all in your network read loop?  Basically, I'm asking if you can easily thread this off.

Comment: @MartinJames The main loop does not need this data, I can handle it all in the network read loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example program that you have chosen to work from is designed to send a single request and receive a single response. It uses the state of the connection to indicate the end of the request, and the end of the response.

You might want to work from a different example program. Search for "winsock chat example" on google.

On the other hand, to modify this program as you have asked, you could replace the do-while loop with this:

```
// Assume that the OP's protocol sends 100-byte packets. 
// Each while iteration attempts to receive one such packet.
// The while exits when the other side closes its connection.
while(1) {
    // Receive 100-byte packet 
    int receivedBytes;
    for(receivedBytes = 0; receivedBytes < 100; ) {
        int iResult = recv(ConnectSocket,
                           recvbuf+receivedBytes,
                           recvbuflen-receivedBytes, 0);

        if ( iResult > 0 ) {
            receivedBytes += iResult;
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
        } else if ( iResult == 0 ) {
            printf("Connection closed\n");
            break;
        } else {
            printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            break;
        }
    }
    if(receivedBytes == 100) {
        // ... process packet here
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it is starting to make sense. I will look into the winsock chat example.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you have no way to know at what point recv() is going to return. There are five workarounds:

1. Make the socket non-blocking. (Not recommendable)
2. Use [select()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with a timeout.
3. Use async sockets. This is probably the fastest way, but more complex.
4. Use a thread.
5. BSD kqueue

Comment: Your #1 and #3 points are totally mutual exclusive. Also, you could also add poll, /dev/poll, epoll, event ports...